# Binding live element status to jquery AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, real-time

Hello I want to bind a element (or variable):

```
$("#progressbar").val(55);
```

to AJAX Request result:

```
$.get("/checkstatus/",...);
// this return the status (a number between 1 and 100 %).
```

and it must be called continuously, to change in real time the progress bar value.

I've tried:

```
$("#progressbar").on() 
... 
$("#progressbar").live()
...
```

but, What is the event to "check continuously" something and bind to a element?. Events like 'click','keyup', ... are not time events.

I've tried also:

```
setTimeout(...)
```

to trigger each **X** seconds a request, but I don't know if it is the best way to do it.

How I can check continuously with AJAX and bind to a element or variable?

Regards:

Comment: `$("#progressbar").value=55;` ==> `$("#progressbar").val('55');`

Comment: [setInterval](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) is the way to do it

Comment: If you dont want to poll the server in regular interval, use WebSockets....that is the accepted protocol for real time communication...

Comment: It depends, setting up web sockets is sometimes a big overkill for only a progress bar.

Comment: You're right @ZoltánTamási ....if the task is simple a progress bar, using WebSockets is too much unnecessary work....my point was for RealTime communication, that can be used...

Comment: better go with server-send events with a settimeout fallback for ie

Comment: WebSocket, for instance, can be used with node.js, true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setInterval` Javascript function which executes a callback periodically at the given millisecond rate. This technique is called *polling*.

However, as much as it is simple, it is not very effective, especially if you have a heavy load. If performance matters, there are other techniques which are more effective. If you're interested, search for *long polling*, *web sockets*, *SignalR* (if you have a .NET backend).

```
var handle = setInterval(function() {
  $.get("/checkstatus/",...)
   .done(function(result) { 
      $("#progressbar").val(result.value); 
      if (result.value >= 100) {
        clearInterval(handle); // stop the cycle
      }      
    });
}, 500); // execute in every 500ms
```

Please note that the code above is not tested, doesn't contain any exception handling and validation, and only ment for a quick example. Do not "copy-paste" it.